# Application Build not loaded on device

Tags: iphone

When I tried to upload a build on device it give the following error.
Your mobile device has encountered an unexpected error `(0xE8000001)`

I am unable to solve this problem. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Anytime i get an unexpected error i hard reboot my device by holding down the home and lock buttons until the apple logo appears.  No idea what causes it, but the reboot usually fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug that is puzzling many users. No idea what the error actually is, but on [this forum](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1994-error-0xe8000001.html) people claim:

> this error will require you to restore your iPhone/touch, either through Xcode's Organizer window or iTunes. No way around it".

Answer (score 0):

This basically happens when there's a communications error between Xcode and the iPhone which leaves Xcode confused about the state the iPhone is in.  (You can actually *make* it happen sometimes by unplugging the phone in the middle of installing a build.)  As the error message's text suggests, turning the iPhone off and back on will usually clear the error.  You may sometimes have to restart Xcode or even your whole Mac, but not often.

Answer (score 0):

To all
The problem get solved. When I set provisioned profile of device. It works.
Thanks for your help & guideline.